# Strange issue with .htaccess file unable to remove PHP extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I am on a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04 x64, and I have enabled `mod_rewrite`.

This works (i.e. correctly redirects to testfile.php):

```
RewriteRule ^othername$ testfile.php
```

But this doesn't (gives me a 404 error, saying "The requested URL /testfile was not found on this server"):

```
RewriteRule ^testfile$ testfile.php
```

So I essentially cannot redirect a URL to a file of the same name but with a PHP extension. The two examples are both working locally with MAMP.
What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Is this a real example? Access log entries? RewriteLog?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the issue, but maybe this solves your problem: `RewriteRule ^(testfile)$ $1.php`

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: Thanks, adding `Options -MultiViews` worked!

Answer (score 0):

As anubhava said, you just have to add `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your .htaccess.